# Rails 4.1.1: JS file in lib/assets/javascripts doesn't load

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have a small JS file (common.js) containing one function. I have the following lines in application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require jquery.readyselector
//= require common
//= require_tree .
```

When I store it in

```
app/assets/javascripts
```

or

```
vendor/assets/javascripts
```

the file is loaded properly, but when I move it to

```
lib/assets/javascripts
```

it stops working and I get the error:

```
Sprockets::FileNotFound
couldn't find file 'common'
(in C:/Sites/rails_studio/beatjoe/app/assets/javascripts/application.js:21)
```

All this eventhough my Rails.application.config.assets.paths is:

```
- C:/Sites/rails_studio/myappname/app/assets/images
- C:/Sites/rails_studio/myappname/app/assets/javascripts
- C:/Sites/rails_studio/myappname/app/assets/stylesheets
- C:/Sites/rails_studio/myappname/lib/assets/javascripts
- C:/Sites/rails_studio/myappname/vendor/assets/fonts
- C:/Sites/rails_studio/myappname/vendor/assets/images
- C:/Sites/rails_studio/myappname/vendor/assets/javascripts
- C:/Sites/rails_studio/myappname/vendor/assets/stylesheets
- C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/turbolinks-2.3.0/lib/assets/javascripts
- C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/jquery-rails-3.1.2/vendor/assets/javascripts
- C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/coffee-rails-4.0.1/lib/assets/javascripts
```

According to the documentation, not only should common.js be included due to

```
//= require common
```

but also be caught by

```
//= require_tree .
```

What am I missing?

Comment: have you tried restarting your server?

Comment: Wow! That worked. Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the `Sprockets::FileNotFound` error by creating the **lib/assets/javascript** directory *while* the local server was running. It appears you need to restart the server to pick up directory changes.

Now that your server has since been restarted, you should be able to add files to the directory without restarting your server.

Comment: Sounds good to me. You're quite right that the "lib" folder (to my surprise) was empty and I had to create the "javascript" folder in it.